# Negative or Positive Linear combination with conditions on weights

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear combination $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n=y$, where $x_i>0$ and $||x||_2=1$. Can we extract any conditions on $a_i$ for the cases $y<0$ and $y>0$?

<sup>PS: I have seen this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671993/linear-combination-of-nonnegative-variables) but it didn't help. I hope my post is not a duplication.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The sum $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i = y$ can be written as a scalar product $a^Tx$ with $a,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. 
This scalar product can be rewritten as
$y=\|x\|_2\|a\|_2 \cos(\measuredangle(x,a))$ i.e. depends on the angle between $x$ and $a$ to determine the sign of $y$.

Can you take it from here?